# How to say “Thank you for being a valued customer”?

Tags: phrase, formality, business-correspondence

I need to say the following in German:

> Thank you for being a valued customer.

I got:

> Als geschätzter Kunde von [Name der Firma], möchten wir uns bei Ihnen herzlich bedanken.

Please advise whether the chosen German sentence is going to be acceptable. Are there any standard phrases to express this?

Comment: Your translation is perfectly fine and gramatically correct.

Comment: **To close voters:** does anybody care to explain what "research effort" is missing, what could further be done to improve the post, or why you believe this still is an off topic  "translation request"?

Comment: It is quite strange to thank someone for the fact that you value them.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where you're saying it, there is a multitude of correct ways to translate the meaning of the English sentence.

It also can *seem* strange to use your own company's name in third person – again depending on where the sentence is supposed to be written/said.

Just to point out a few more ways of putting it:

> Für das in uns gesetzte Vertrauen möchten wir uns bei Ihnen herzlich bedanken
>
> Wir freuen uns, dass wir Sie als geschätzten Kunden erneut begrüßen dürfen/durften

Or, if used in the beginning of a letter:

> Sehr geehrte/r X,
>
> da Sie schon seit (timeframe Z) bei der Firma Y treuer Kunde sind, möchten wir uns bei Ihnen mit folgendem Angebot bedanken:

(I would probably still not use `Firma Y` in third person, though.)

I put emphasis on all relativising words just to show that there are so many possible options; there is not *the one phrase* that fits all. There is also a large amount of personal preference, both on the sending and on the receiving side.

Answer (score 3):

"*Als* geschätzter Kunde von (Name der Firma) ... , möchten wir uns bei Ihnen herzlich bedanken" would be in English: "*As* = *Being a* valued customer of XY, we would like to thank you.."

*Als* always equates two entities, grammatically signified *by matching cases*, which, in this sentence, would translate to: "We, as valued customers of XY, thank you very much..." The only evidence what the message is really meant to be, is that "Kunde" and "wir" don't match.

Therefore, you can only say:

> Wir möchten uns bei Ihnen, als einem geschätzten Kunden unserer Firma, für Ihre Treue herzlich bedanken.

or:

> Wir schätzen Sie außerordentlich als Kunden unserer Firma und möchten uns bei Ihnen für Ihre Treue herzlich bedanken.